# Отсортировать список по кастомному ключу

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

Необходимо отсортировать список по кастомному ключу.
У меня имеется словарь `Users = { ID, User }` и класс:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def add(self):
        self.count += 1

    def getCount(self):
        return self.count
```

Я получаю список *ID* (ключей словаря) `x = list(Users.keys())`,
и теперь мне нужно его отсортировать по значению метода `getCount()` объектов словаря `Users[ID]`. Я пробую создать функцию для сортировки в виде:

```
def sortByCount(arg):
    return Users[arg].getCount()

#Сразу сортирую и вывожу лист в консоль
print(x.sort(key=sortByLikes))

#Вывод: None  - вместо ожидаемого мной списка
```

Возникает вопрос: как можно отсортировать список *ID* по возвращаемому значению метода `getCount()` объекта из словаря?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sort изменяет список и возвращет None.

```
def sortByCount(arg):
    return Users[arg].getCount()

x.sort(key=sortByLikes)
print(x)
```

или так:

```
print(sorted(x, key=sortByLikes)
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял ошибку. Надо документацию внимательней читать)

Comment: отметьте ответ как правильный

Answer (score 3):

Можно (и лучше) использовать лямбды для простых случаев:

```
print(sorted(x, key=lambda x: Users[x].getCount())
```